# Adjust number of ticks in R levelplot

Tags: r, levelplot

I have a following R code:

```
library(lattice)
x <- rep(seq(6,15,by=1), each=20)
y <- rep(seq(0,0.95,by=0.05), 10)
z <- x*y
levelplot(z ~ x * y)
```

It produces this plot:
[image]

How can I have ticks at 6, 7, ..., 15 on x-axis and ticks at 0.0, 0.1, ..., 0.9 on y-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(lattice)
x <- rep(seq(6,15,by=1), each=20)
y <- rep(seq(0,0.95,by=0.05), 10)
z <- x*y

x.scale <- list(at=seq(6,15,1))
y.scale <- list(at=seq(0,0.9,0.1))

levelplot(z ~ x * y, scales=list(x=x.scale, y=y.scale))
```

[image]